# how to install production group in the Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

my gem file consists :

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

when i give the `bundle install` command ,at the end i get the line

```
"Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed."
```

How to install production group.?

Comment: As a side-note: why would you specify a `production` group? In general we specify explicit development/test gems which are excluded in production. You will always need the production gems, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your `.bundle/config` file you probably have this line:

```
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production
```

Just delete this line, and the `bundle install` will also install the gems from the `production` group

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps,

1. `bundle install --without development`
2. `bundle install #remembers and includes --without development`
3. `bundle install --without nothing`

And now bundler installs all the gems.

Or you can directly try this one to install production group's gems only,

```
bundle install --without development test
```