# Unrecognized constant Faker in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

I'm using `seeds.rb` to populate my db on my dev server running in production mode.

Inside the seeds file I'm using the Faker gem to generate random values. In development mode everything works fine. But if I try to seed in production mode I get an error that Faker is not recognized.

Gemfile:

```ruby
group :production do
   gem 'faker'
end
```

Seeds.rb:

```ruby
require 'faker'

user = User.create(name: Faker::Name.name)
```

So if I run `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production` I get the error message: `NameError: uninitialized constant Faker`.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after changing Gemfile?

Comment: You might check your Gemfile and ensure the production group includes Faker.

Comment: Check if `bundle install` actually installed the gem in the `production` group. You may encounter something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802514/232838.

Comment: Yes, I did run `bundle install`. How would I check if the gem is installed in production? I don't have a `.bundle/config` file.

Comment: `uninitialized constant Faker`, but from which file does this error originate?

Comment: it's coming from `seeds.rb`

Comment: @crispychicken check by ‘gem list’

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `faker` gem completely from the `Gemfile` then made a `bundle install`. After that I added the gem back to the file and `bundle install` again.

Now it is working. So the issue was, bundle didn't put it in production the first time I installed.